# How do align this to center of section?

Tags: html, css, center

I have problem aligning three boxes to the center of section.

Here is what I have so far:

```css
 
 /*==============Custome Css ====================*/
 
 
 .slider_patch {
   background: rgba(63, 61, 61, 0.61);
  padding: 0px 15px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 28px #2F2F2F;
}
 
 button.small.skyblue a {
color: #fff;
}
 
 /*==============Custome Css ====================*/
 
 
 
 /* #Misc
 ================================================== */
 
 /* EXTRAS */
 
 .brdr-r1, .brdr-r2 { border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5; padding-right: 19px; }
 .brdr-l1, .brdr-l2 { border-left: 1px solid #e5e5e5; padding-left: 19px; }
 .brdr-r2 { padding-right: 27px; }
 .brdr-l2 { padding-left: 27px; }
 .pad-r27 { padding-right: 27px; }
 .pad-l27 { padding-left: 27px; }
 .alignright { text-align: right; }
 img.alignright { float: right; }
 .alignleft { text-align: left; }
 img.alignleft { float: left; }
 .aligncenter { text-align: center; }
 .wp-caption { display: block; color: #444; }
 .wp-caption-text { font-size: 15px; }
 .sticky { color: #555; }
 .gallery-caption { display: inline; }
 .bypostauthor { font-size: 13px; }
 .moonicons-box1 { font-size: 16px; display: inline-block; width: 15em; padding: .25em .5em; background: #fff; margin: .5em 1em .5em 0; border: 1px solid #e8e8e8; }
 .alignright { text-align: right; }
 img.alignright { float: right; }
 .alignleft { text-align: left; }
 img.alignleft { float: left; }
 .aligncenter { text-align: center; }
 .wp-caption { display: block; color: #444; }
 .wp-caption-text { font-size: 15px; }
 .sticky { color: #555; }
 .gallery-caption { display: inline; }
 .bypostauthor { font-size: 13px; }
 /* Scroll to top */
 #scroll-top a { width: 16px; height: 16px; padding: 6px 8px 9px; border-radius: 4px; background: #818c90; position: fixed; bottom: 48px; right: 32px; display: none; opacity: 0.89; filter: alpha(opacity=89); z-index: 499841; }
 #scroll-top a i { font-size: 16px; color: #fff; display:block; }
 #scroll-top a:hover { background-color: #ffcc00; cursor: pointer; }
 
 h1.pnf404 { font-size: 176px; line-height: 1.1; font-weight:900;}
 h2.pnf404 { font-size: 42px; line-height: 1.2; font-weight:700; }
 input.txbx404 { float:left; margin-top:2px; margin-right:4px; padding:7px 4px; min-height:inherit; border-radius:3px; }
 input.btn404 { float:left; margin:1px; padding:8px 12px 9px; }
 
 .v-shadow-l { background:url(../images/v-shadow-left.png) no-repeat right center; }
 .v-shadow-r { background:url(../images/v-shadow-right.png) no-repeat left center; }
 .v-shadow-r, .v-shadow-l {  min-height:320px; }
 .pad-r10 { padding-right:10px; }
 .pad-r20 { padding-right:20px; }
 .pad-r30 { padding-right:30px; }
 .pad-r40 { padding-right:40px; }
 .pad-l10 { padding-left:10px; }
 .pad-l20 { padding-left:20px; }
 .pad-l30 { padding-left:30px; }
 .pad-l40 { padding-left:40px; }
 
 /* #Column Shortcodes
 ----------- */
 .one_half, .one_third, .two_third, .three_fourth, .one_fourth, .one_fifth, .two_fifth { margin-right: 3%; float: left; margin-bottom:2px; }
 .one_half {  width: 48%; }
 .one_third { width: 30.6666%; }
 .two_third { width: 65.3332%; }
 .one_fourth { width: 22%; }
 .three_fourth { width: 74%; }
 .one_fifth { width: 16.8%; }
 .two_fifth  { width: 37.6%; }
 .column-last { margin-right: 0 !important; clear: right; }
 
 
 .easyPieChart { position: relative; text-align: center; }
 .easyPieChart canvas { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
 .pie { text-align:center; font-size:49px; position:relative; margin:0 auto 20px; }
 .pie p { font-size:16px; color:#888; font-weight:400; position:absolute; bottom:-52px; width:100%; padding-top:10px; border-top:2px solid #f9f9f9;}
 .container .pie p { margin-bottom:0;}
 
 
 
 /* #Media Queries
 ================================================== */
 
 /* Smaller than standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
 @media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {
 
 .img-box { width: 256px; height: 188px; }
 .last-project .img-box { background: #EA3C3C; }
 .last-project .img-box:nth-child(even) { background: #F66060; }
 .ab-box { height: 235px; }
 .author-detail { width: 218px; }
 .comment-contents { width: 343px; }
 .child-comment .comment-contents { width: 263px; }
 .contact input { width: 330px; float: none; }
 .contact textarea { width: 486px; }
 .row.magic, .s-qoute-man { padding: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; }
 a.get { margin-bottom: 14px; }
 .pad-r10, .pad-r20, .pad-r30, .pad-r40 { padding-right: 5px; }
 .pad-l10, .pad-l20, .pad-l30, .pad-l40 { padding-left: 5px; }
 #main-content-pin .container { width: auto; }
 
 }
 
 /* Tablet Portrait size to standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
 @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
 
 #boxed-wrap { width: 828px; }
 .social-icons a { margin: 1px 4px 0 4px; }
 .row.magic { padding-left: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px; }
 #tline-content { width: 800px; }
 .tline-box { width: 335px; }
 /*#nav a span, #nav a:after { font-size:9px;  }*/
 
 .blog-date-sec { width: 42px; height: 42px; }
 .help-box { width: 50%; }
 
 }
 
 /* All Mobile Sizes (devices and browser) */
 @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 
 .sidebar, .rgt-cntt, .sidebar.leftside { padding-right:0; background:none; padding-top:40px; margin-top:40px; border-top:5px solid #e5e5e5;}
 .rgt-cntt, .sidebar.leftside { padding-top:0px; margin-top:0px; border-top:0 none;}
 .contact-form .txbx { width:224px;}
 .pricing-table .plans-f-list.respo { display:inline; visibility:visible;}
 #header.super-fixed { height:auto; box-shadow:none; border-bottom:4px solid #f0f0f0;}
 #headline { height:auto; border-bottom:3px solid #f3f3f3; padding:14px 0; }
 #headline h3 { border-top-color:#f6f6f6; font-size:37px; text-align:center;}
 #headline h3 small { display:block; margin-top:14px; margin-bottom:0; font-size:16px; letter-spacing:0; font-weight:400; }
 .servobx, .servobx div, .servobx img, ul#main-ibox li, ul#main-ibox li.active9  { width:100%; float:none;}
 #search-form { display:none; }
 #header .alignright, top-inf.alignright { text-align:center;}
 #search-form2 { display:block; }
 #side-content { padding-bottom:30px; border-bottom:5px solid #f3f3f3; margin-bottom:40px;}
 
 .top-bar { height:65px; padding:5px 0 6px; background:url(../images/topsobg1.png) repeat-x center center; white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden;}
 .top-bar h6 { font-size:11px; letter-spacing:0; margin:0 10px 0 0;}
 .top-bar h6 i { font-size:12px; width: 12px; height: 12px; text-align: center; padding:3px; margin-right:3px; }
 .top-bar .socailfollow, .top-links, .top-links.rgtflot, .top-bar .socailfollow.lftflot { float:none; text-align:center; clear:both; min-height:22px;}
 .top-bar .socailfollow, .top-bar .socailfollow.lftflot  {  padding-top:8px;}
 .top-bar .socailfollow a, .top-bar .socailfollow.lftflot a, .top-links p, .top-links img { float:none; display:inline; padding-top:10px; background:none;}
 .top-links, .top-links.rgtflot { margin:0 0 8px 0; padding-top:4px; }
 .top-links.rgtflot { margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:6px;}
 
 .container hr { margin-left:0; margin-right:0;}
 .blog-date-sec { border:0 none; margin:0; text-align:left; border-bottom:1px solid #e5e5e5; background:#fdfdfd;}
 .blog-post { border-bottom-width:3px;}
 
 .nav-search { float: none; margin: 0; }
 .img-box { width: 420px; height: 308px; }
 .comment-contents { width: 328px; margin-right: 0; }
 .child-comment .comment-contents { width: 248px; }
 .contact textarea { width: 398px; }
 
 .author-detail { margin: 20px 0; }
 .blog-date-sec { width: auto; display:block; -webkit-border-radius: 0; -moz-border-radius: 0; border-radius: 0; border: none; border-bottom: 2px solid #e3e3e3; margin-bottom: 5px; }
 .blog-date-sec span, .blog-date-sec h3 { display: inline; margin: 0 10px; line-height: 50px; }
 .blog-date-sec span { font-size: 20px; font-weight: 300; }
 .blog-date-sec h3 { font-size: 32px;}
 
 .contact-form .txbx { width: 224px; }
 .pricing-table .plans-f-list.respo { display: inline; visibility: visible; }
 #headline h3 { border-top-color: #f6f6f6; }
 .image-gallery ul li, .image-gallery ul li img { display:block; width:auto; max-width:100%; height:auto; float:none;}
 

 input[type="text"].header-saerch, input[type="text"].header-saerch:focus { width: 261px; margin-top: 10px; }
 .logo { text-align: center; }
 .pin-box { width: 256px; }
 
 .tline-box .blog-date-sp { width: 80%; }
 .tline-box .blog-com-sp { width: 0; display: none; }
 .tabs-left > .nav-tabs, .tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a, .nav-tabs > li, .nav-tabs > li.active, .tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li.active > a, .tabs-left > .nav-tabs .active > a:hover { width:100%; display:block; padding-left:0; padding-right:0; }
 .tabs-left > .nav-tabs > li > a { border-right:0 none;}
 .tabs-left > .tab-content { border:0 none;}
 .tab-content .columns, .tab-content .column { margin:0 10px; max-width:90%; }

 .date-sp-wrap { margin: 0; float: right; margin-bottom: 7px; }
 .blog-line .blog-date-sec { height: auto; }
 .v-shadow-r, .v-shadow-l { min-height: inherit; background: none; }
 .pad-r10, .pad-r20, .pad-r30, .pad-r40, .pad-l10, .pad-l20, .pad-l30, .pad-l40 { padding: 0; }
 .one_half, .one_third, .two_third, .three_fourth, .one_fourth, .one_fifth, .two_fifth { width: 100%; float: none; margin-right: 0; }
 .latest-f-blog, .qot-week { margin:0;}
 .callout { margin:10px 0px 20px; }
 .brdr-l1, brdr-r1 { padding:0; border:0 none; }
 .brdr-l1 { margin-top:30px;}
 .tab-content p, .tab-content li { font-size: 12px; }
 .help-box { width: 100%; }
 .ab-box { height: auto; padding-bottom: 25px; }
 input[type="text"].header-saerch, input[type="text"].header-saerch:focus { float: none; display: inline; position: relative; z-index: 10000; }
 .jcarousel-next, .jcarousel-prev { padding:12px; }
 .jcarousel-prev { right:38px;}
 .jcarousel-next:after, .jcarousel-prev:after { top:13px; right:13px;}
 .our-clients-wrap .jcarousel-next, .our-clients-wrap .jcarousel-prev { padding:10px;}
 
 
 .is-sticky, .is-sticky #header { position:relative; height:auto;}
 .is-sticky #header { margin-top:0;}
 .is-sticky .logo { height:auto; margin-top:0; }
 .is-sticky .logo img { max-height:auto; height:auto; }

 }
 
 /* Mobile Landscape Size to Tablet Portrait (devices and browsers) */
 @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
 
 .help-block { height: auto; }
 #boxed-wrap { width: 460px; }
 .page-subtitle { left: 0; padding: 10px 0 0 20px; bottom: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #e8edee; margin-bottom: 20px; height: auto; width: auto; clear: both; background: #fdfdfd; border-radius: 0; }
 .contact-form .txbx { width: 338px; }
 .pricing-table .plans-f-list.respo { display: inline; visibility: visible; }
 .jcarousel-item, .last-project .portfolio-item { max-width: 210px; height: 157px; float: left; }
 .pin-box { width: 166px; width: 164px\9; }
 #tline-content { width: 460px; }
 .tline-box { width: 165px; }
 }
 
 /* Mobile Portrait Size to Mobile Landscape Size (devices and browsers) */
 @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
 
 .nav-wrap2.mn4 #nav a { padding: 15px 4px; }
 #menu a { padding: 15px 4px; }
 .img-box { width: 300px; height: 220px; }
 
 .author-detail { width: 254px; }
 .author-arrow { width: 11px; height: 6px; background: url('../images/testimonial-arrow-top.png') no-repeat; left: 25px; top: -6px; }
 .contact input { width: 288px; margin-right: 0; }
 .contact textarea { width: 278px; }
 #boxed-wrap { width: 340px; }
 .footbot { min-height: 38px; height: auto; }
 
 .page-subtitle { left: 0; padding: 10px 0 0 20px; bottom: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #e8edee; margin-bottom: 20px; height: auto; width: auto; clear: both; background: #fdfdfd; border-radius: 0; }
 .pricing-table .plans-f-list.respo { display: inline; visibility: visible; }
 .pricing-table ul { width: 136px; }
 .pricing-table ul li { width: 124px; padding: 5px; }
 .pricing-table ul li.plan-header, .pricing-table ul li .plan-title, .pricing-table ul li .plan-price { max-width: 136px; }
 .pricing-table ul li.plan-footer { max-width: 114px; }
 .portfolio-item { margin-bottom: 14px; }
 .commentin { width: 92%; }
 
 #tline-content { width: 300px; }
 .tline-box { width: 250px; }
 .tline-row-l, .tline-row-r { display: none }
 .tline-box.rgtline { float: left; left: 0; }
 }
 
 @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) { 
 
  #boxed-wrap { width:1180px;}
  .white-space { height:110px;}
   h4.subtitle { margin:39px 0 21px 0; }
  #main-content-pin .container { padding:0 40px; }
  .sidebar.leftside { background-position: 295px; padding-right:70px; }
  .blog-date-sec h3 { font-size:36px;}
 
  } 
 
 
 @media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
 /* ensure #nav is visible on desktop version */
 #nav { display: block !important; }
 .ls-layer h1, .ls-layer h3 { left:10px;}
 
 } 
 
 
 
 button.small.skyblue.demooo {
  width: 65%;
  /*border-bottom: 6px solid rgb(0, 150, 192);*/
}
 
 li.color {
  background-color: rgb(197, 197, 197);
  padding: 4px;
}


section.container.first-block.aligncenter.colorbar {
  /*background: rgb(0, 173, 239);*/
  /* width: 100%; */
  /* left: 10px; */
  padding: 0px 38px 0px 38px;
}
 h4.slight.frontsight {
  color: #333;
}

figure.shop-item.one_fourth.boxwrap {
  background: white;
  margin-bottom:35px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42);
  /*margin-right:10px;
  width: 17%;*/
  /* padding: 6px; */
  /* left: 99px; */
  /* color: black; */
  /* padding: 0px; */
  /* top: 18px; */
}


 
 h4.fronttext {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 24px;
  /* color: black !important; */
}
figure.shop-item.one_fourth.boxwrap:hover {
  background: rgba(239, 239, 239, 1);
  /* color: white; */
}
 /* --------Custom CSS-------------*/
table {
  width:100%;
 }
table  tr{
 height:20px;
 }
table tr td p{
 margin-bottom:0px;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
 background-color: rgb(166, 206, 244);
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
 background-color: rgb(207, 230, 252);
}

tr:nth-child(even):hover {
 background-color: rgb(242, 244, 245);
}
tr:nth-child(odd):hover {
 background-color: rgb(242, 244, 245);
}

td:nth-child(even) {
 vertical-align:middle;
 text-align:left;
 padding:10px;
}
td:nth-child(odd) {
 vertical-align:middle;
 text-align:left;
 padding:10px;
}
.parallax-sec .blox{
 padding:20px 0 0px;
}
.eleven.columns .shop-wrap figure{
 margin-right: 3%;
}

table.product-details caption{
 float:left;
}

.product-details{
 width:100%;
}

.contact-inf p{
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
.response{
 height:600px;
 width:80%;
 margin:0 auto;
 display:block;
 padding:60px 50px;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:14;
}
.ls-layer h2{
 font-size:40px !important;
}
/*---------Custom CSS--------------*/
```

```html
<section class="container first-block aligncenter colorbar">
    <hr class="vertical-space3">
    <h2 class="mex-title">Welcome to the Polymers Enterprises</h2>
    <h4 class="slight frontsight">Scaling new heights on the strength of Excellence, Efficiency &amp; Ethics</h4>
    <hr class="vertical-space3">
    <div class="services">
    <div class="one_fourth">
     <article class="icon-box1"><i class="fa-user"></i>
      <h5>ABOUT US</h5>
      <p>For over 30 years, Polymers Enterprises has developed a record of service, growth and reliability unsurpassed....</p>
      <button type="button" class="small skyblue demooo" onclick="window.location.href='about.html'">Read more</button>
     </article>
    </div>
    <!--<div class="one_fourth">
     <article class="icon-box1"><i class="li_bulb"></i>
      <h5>EFFICIENCY</h5>
      <p>We have made good relationship with customers by supplying them excellent quality products, which help us to ...</p>
      <button type="button" class="small skyblue demooo" onclick="window.location.href='about.html'">Read more</button>
     </article>
    </div>-->
    <div class="one_fourth">
     <article class="icon-box1"><i class="li_note"></i>
      <h5>WHAT WE DO</h5>
      <p>Our policy is to achieve Quality in supply chain and maximize the serviceability to the client coupled with quality of cost....</p>
      <button type="button" class="small skyblue demooo" onclick="window.location.href='about.html'">Read more</button>
     </article>
    </div>
    <div class="one_fourth column-last">
     <article class="icon-box1"><i class="fa-cubes"></i>
      <h5>OUR PRODUCTS</h5>
      <p>Polymer Enterprises provides a wide range of products and consulting services to customers .....</p>
      <button type="button" class="small skyblue demooo" onclick="window.location.href='our_products.html'">Read more</button>
     </article>
    </div>
    </div>
   </section>
```

I have tried giving `width` `display:block`, `display:inline-block` and `margin: 0 auto` but no luck.Also I have been to almost all questions here but noone helped me. Can anyone help me get it sorted?

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/salunkheganesh07/0567yqkm/1/)

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making them `display: inline-block` does work, you just need to remove the float.

```
.one_half, .one_third, .two_third, .three_fourth, .one_fourth, .one_fifth, .two_fifth {
    margin-right: 3%;
    display: inline-block; /* remove float and add display inline-block */
    margin-bottom:2px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/0567yqkm/2/)

**Note:** *Add `vertical-align:top;` if you want the content in each to line up, **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/0567yqkm/3/).***